# Elementary Vectors proof

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces

This question is basically based on elementary vector laws like the polygon law of vectors.Here's how it goes:

Let there be six vectors $A_1,\dots, A_6 $ taken head to tail arranged in the form of a regular hexagon.Use the fact that the resultant of these vectors is zero to prove that :
$$\cos 0 + \cos \frac{\pi}{3} + \cos \frac{2\pi}{3}+\cos\frac{3\pi}{3}+\cos \frac{4\pi}{3}+\cos\frac{5\pi}3=0 $$

Thanks for any Help.

Comment: What are the coordinates of the sum of your six vectors?

Comment: Use the fact that the resultant of these vectors is zero to prove .If you want to take co-ordinates then chose one of them as origin and solve. But it would be better if you prove without that .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No generality is lost by assuming they're vectors of unit length.  (Can you figure out why not?)

Then the dot products of any one of them with all of them are $\cos0$, $\cos\frac\pi3$, $\cos\frac{2\pi}3$, etc.  The dot product of their sum with that one of them is $0$.  And $A_1\cdot(A_1+\cdots+A_6)$ $=(A_1\cdot A_1)+(A_1\cdot A_2)+\cdots+(A_1\cdot A_6)$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  2-d vectors can be represented in terms of angles by using cosine for the x-coordinate and sine for the y-cooordinate, i.e. any 2-d vector has the form $(A\cos(\theta), A\sin(\theta))$ for some choice of angle $\theta$ and some $A \geq 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You are free to *choose* a regular hexagon that will make it easier to prove the identity you want. In particular, you can choose $A_1=(1,0)$. Given this choice, what are $A_2$ through $A_6$?